# How to return an empty result cursor on publication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How do I return an empty cursor?

```
Meteor.publish('example', function(id) {
    check(id, Match.Maybe(String))
    if (!this.userId) return []
})
```

In this example, the publication should give me an empty result if user is not logged in. But doing it like shown above gives me the error

```
Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tell the subscriber that the collection is ready, but not provide any data, like this:

```
return this.ready();
```

there are other options, like stop() and error(), depending on how you want the client to behave. they're covered in the Meteor guide:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish